# NSDate is uninitialized in swift 2.0

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

let theDate:NSDate = dateFor.dateFromString(date)! provides the error

unexpectadly found nil while unwrapping an optional value, theDate returns as uninitialized and as nil.

```
 if let date = review.createdAt {
            let dateFor:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFor.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
            dateFor.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
            let theDate:NSDate = dateFor.dateFromString(date)!
            let tempoDate = Tempo(date: theDate)
            let timeStamp = tempoDate.timeAgoNow()
            if let reviewString = review.description {
                let review = NSMutableAttributedString(string: reviewString + "  -  ")
                let x = NSAttributedString(string: timeStamp, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.lightGrayColor()])
                review.appendAttributedString(x)
                vivrcell.reviewDescription.attributedText = review
                vivrcell.reviewDescription.sizeToFit()

            }
        }
```

Why is this happening how do i fix it? this worked in swift 1.2

Comment: Have you single-stepped through to see which statement is causing the problem? Or even added `print` statements? Then when the problem is isolated ask a question about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
dateFor.dateFromString(date)!
```

returns nil because 'date' contains a wrongly formatted string which can not be converted to a date. But you are force unwrapping it, that creates the error. Instead of force unwrapping it with ! do it with an if let:

```
if let parsedDate = dateFor.dateFromString(date) { ... }
```

to check if the parsing works.